# Flattening events table in SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an `events` table that contains 3 event types for each campaign and person. The 3 events are "Received Email", "Opened Email" and "Clicked Email". I want to be able to get the timestamp of each event for a person/campaign as a new column in the table. What's the best way of doing that?

Sample table data:

```
campaign_id     person_id     event_type     timestamp

1               1             Received Email 2018-01-01
1               1             Opened Email   2018-02-01
1               1             Clicked Email  2018-03-01
1               2             Received Email 2018-01-01
1               2             Opened Email   2018-02-01
1               2             Opened Email   2018-02-02
```

Sample output:

```
    campaign_id     person_id     event_type     timestamp     receive_ts     open_ts     click_ts

    1               1             Received Email 2018-01-01    2018-01-01     2018-02-01  2018-03-01
    1               1             Opened Email   2018-02-01    2018-01-01     2018-02-01  2018-03-01
    1               1             Clicked Email  2018-03-01    2018-01-01     2018-02-01  2018-03-01
    1               2             Received Email 2018-01-01    2018-01-01     2018-02-01
    1               2             Opened Email   2018-02-01    2018-01-01     2018-02-01
    1               2             Opened Email   2018-02-02    2018-01-01     2018-02-01
```

The only solution that comes to my mind is to join the table to itself 3 times on campaign_id and person_id, once for each event type, but the table contains more than 400m rows, so that would obviously not be efficient.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and No - you do not need to do three JOINs - you don't even need any JOINs here

```
#standardSQL
SELECT campaign_id, person_id, event_type, ts,
  FIRST_VALUE(IF(event_type='Received Email', ts, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win) receive_ts,
  FIRST_VALUE(IF(event_type='Opened Email', ts, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win) open_ts,
  FIRST_VALUE(IF(event_type='Clicked Email', ts, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win) click_ts
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY campaign_id, person_id ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your question  as

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 campaign_id, 1 person_id, 'Received Email' event_type, '2018-01-01' ts UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, 'Opened Email', '2018-02-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, 'Clicked Email', '2018-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 'Received Email', '2018-01-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 'Opened Email', '2018-02-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 'Opened Email', '2018-02-02' 
)
SELECT campaign_id, person_id, event_type, ts,
  FIRST_VALUE(IF(event_type='Received Email', ts, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win) receive_ts,
  FIRST_VALUE(IF(event_type='Opened Email', ts, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win) open_ts,
  FIRST_VALUE(IF(event_type='Clicked Email', ts, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win) click_ts
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY campaign_id, person_id ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
-- ORDER BY campaign_id, person_id, ts
```

the result should be

```
Row campaign_id person_id   event_type      ts          receive_ts  open_ts     click_ts     
1   1           1           Received Email  2018-01-01  2018-01-01  2018-02-01  2018-03-01   
2   1           1           Opened Email    2018-02-01  2018-01-01  2018-02-01  2018-03-01   
3   1           1           Clicked Email   2018-03-01  2018-01-01  2018-02-01  2018-03-01   
4   1           2           Received Email  2018-01-01  2018-01-01  2018-02-01  null     
5   1           2           Opened Email    2018-02-01  2018-01-01  2018-02-01  null     
6   1           2           Opened Email    2018-02-02  2018-01-01  2018-02-01  null
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try using a pivot query here.  For example, if you wanted the difference in minutes for each person/campaign from the time of receiving an email to opening that email, you could try this:

```
SELECT
    campaign_id,
    person_id,
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
        MAX(CASE WHEN event_type = 'Opened Email' THEN timestamp END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN event_type = 'Received Email' THEN timestamp END),
        MINUTE) AS diff_in_minutes
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    campaign_id,
    person_id;
```

Note: This answer was given to the original question, which was later changed substantially.

Comment: thanks! I realized that I didn't fully explain myself initially, so I've made some edits to the question!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not changing my answer.  If you want to view more diffs between the two events, then just duplicate the call I am making to `TIMESTAMP_DIFF`.

Comment: That's not quite the change I'm looking for. See the sample output I now have in the question. Thanks for your help, and no worries if you don't want to change your answer.