# How can I flatten table in SQL in Google Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this table

[image]

And tried to achieve the following output:
[image]

I found different articles (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113459/flattening-events-table-in-sql-bigquery)) how to do it, unfortunately they do not work with my table.

The schema of the table is the following:
[image]

Comment: you should show exact schema of your table otherwise no way to help you

Comment: no way to answer this without knowing what exactly structure of `table.keyvalue.list.element....`! record, repeated record, etc. ...?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant T I added the schema to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach - less verbose and easy to manage if any adjustments needed

```
select * from (
  select id_car, kv.element.key, kv.element.value
  from `project.dataset.table`, unnest(table.keyvalue.list) as kv
)
pivot (min(value) for key in ('id', 'model', 'status', 'speed'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I created a table with the schema you mentioned and data you gave:

[image]

[image]

I ran the following query on this table:

```
Select id_car,STRING_AGG(id,'') as id, STRING_AGG(model,'') as model, STRING_AGG(Status,'') as status, STRING_AGG(speed,'') as speed from (SELECT id_car,
if(my.element.key = "id", my.element.value,'') as id,
if(my.element.key = "model", my.element.value, '') as `model`,
if(my.element.key = "Status", my.element.value, '') as Status,
if(my.element.key = "speed", my.element.value, '') as speed,
FROM `ProjectID.Dataset.Table`, unnest(table.keyvalue.list) as my) group by id_car
```

This gives me the same output that you expect:

[image]